# How do I implement TypeAdapterFactory in Gson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

How do I implement type [TypeAdapterFactory](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) in Gson?

The main method of create is generic. Why?

The registration method [registerTypeAdapterFactory()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapterFactory%28com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory%29) does not receive type a type argument. So, how does `Gson` know which classes are processed by the factory?

Should I implement one factory for multiple classes, or can I implement one for many classes?

If I implement one factory for multiple classes, then what should I return in case of out-of-domain type argument?

Answer (score 49):

When you register a regular type adapter (`GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter`), it only generates a type adapter for THAT specific class. For example:

```
public abstract class Animal { abstract void speak(); }
public class Dog extends Animal {
   private final String speech = "woof";
   public void speak() {
       System.out.println(speech);
   }
}

// in some gson related method
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Animal.class, myTypeAdapterObject);
Gson g = gsonBuilder.create();
Dog dog = new Dog();
System.out.println(g.toJson(dog));
```

If you did this, then `Gson` will **not** use your `myTypeAdapterObject`, it will use the default type adapter for `Object`.

So, how can you make a type adapter object that can convert ANY `Animal` subclass to Json? Create a `TypeAdapterFactory`! The factory can match using the generic type and the `TypeToken` class. You should return null if your `TypeAdapterFactory` doesn't know how to handle an object of that type.

The other thing `TypeAdapterFactory` can be used for is that you can't CHAIN adapters any other way. By default, Gson doesn't pass your `Gson` instance into the `read` or `write` methods of `TypeAdapter`. So if you have an object like:

```
public class MyOuterClass {
    private MyInnerClass inner;
}
```

There is no way to write your `TypeAdapter<MyOuterClass>` that knows how to use your `TypeAdapter<MyInnerClass>` without using the `TypeAdapterFactory`. The `TypeAdapterFactory.create` method DOES pass the `Gson` instance, which allows you to teach your `TypeAdapter<MyOuterClass>` how to serialize the `MyInnerClass` field.

---

Generally, here is a good standard way to begin to write an implementation of a `TypeAdapterFactory`:

```
public enum FooAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    INSTANCE; // Josh Bloch's Enum singleton pattern

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (!Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) return null;

        // Note: You have access to the `gson` object here; you can access other deserializers using gson.getAdapter and pass them into your constructor
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new FooAdapter();
    }

    private static class FooAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Foo> {
        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, Foo value) {
            // your code
        }

        @Override
        public Foo read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, will `Gson` call my adapter factory for hundreds of classes met during serialization?

Comment: yes, but `Gson` keeps a lookup table of `class` to `AdapterFactory` so it only tries your class once. if `create` returns null it never tries for that class again.

Comment: where is it documented?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Umm yeah... I figured that out looking at the source code :-D

Comment: @SuzanCioc This doesn't explain that bit of it but it is still a very good reference: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html

Comment: If `FooAdapter` is the only Adapter that can be provided then why use an `TypeAdapterFactory`? Why not just use a `TypeAdapter`?

Comment: Because a `TypeAdapter<T>` can only serialize one specific type, `T`. If you want to serialize an interface and all implementors, you need to create a reference in the Gson lookup table for **all** requested classes that implement that interface.

Comment: Could you kindly write deserialize example with Animal interface and Cat, Dog class ? Thanks!

Comment: This work-around works, but clashes with my ExclusionStrategy which tells gson to ignore some fields. Gson obviously removes all reference to the fields excluded before it gets to the deserialization step, because those ignored fields in the JSON now causes the ValidationTypeAdapter to throw an unknown field exception!