# Using gson fromjson to parse sub classes

Tags: java, json, inheritance, gson

I am using Gson to parse a json string into a `Vector` which stores 1-2 different sub-classes of `BackgroundShape`.
Example, `BGRectangle` and `BGTriangle`.
When I try to parse the string I get this error ..

```
FileReader in = new FileReader("levels/level1.json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
LevelDefinition ld = new Gson().fromJson(br, LevelDefinition.class);

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?
I'm trying to place sub classes into a Vector of their parents type.
This is the parent class ..

```
public abstract class Shape{

    protected int textureIndex;

    /**
     * @param textureIndex
     */
    public Shape(int textureIndex) {
        this.textureIndex = textureIndex;
    }

    protected abstract void draw(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable);
}
```

`BackgroundShape` subclasses `Shape` ..

```
public abstract class BackgroundShape extends Shape{

    private Vec3 position;

    public BackgroundShape(Vec3 position, int textureIndex) {
        super(textureIndex);

        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

`BGRectangle` extends `BackgroundShape` ..

```
public class BGRectangle extends BackgroundShape{

    private float width;
    private float height;

    public BGRectangle (Vec3 position int textureIndex, float width, float height) { 
        super(position, textureIndex);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    };

    @Override
    public void draw(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
    }
}
```

This is how I declare in json (only 1 `BackgroundShape` for demo) ..

```
{
    "bgShapes": [
        {
            "position": {
                "x": 0.0,
                "y": 50.0,
                "z": -20.0
            },
                    "textureSelection": 1,
            "width": 450.0,
            "height": 200.0
        }
    ]
}
```

And my Java class representing this json string ..

```
public class LevelDefinition {

    private Vector<BackgroundShape> bgShapes;

    /**
     * @return the bgShapes
     */
    public Vector<BackgroundShape> getBgShapes() {
        return bgShapes;
    }
    /**
     * @param bgShapes the bgShapes to set
     */
    public void setBgShapes(Vector<BackgroundShape> bgShapes) {
        this.bgShapes = bgShapes;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any info there that will tell Gson that it needs to create BGRectangles.  I'm guessing it gets lost looking for somewhere to put width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=440) to me.

The way I worked around it is to write my own `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter`. You can read more about how to do this in my answer here: [How do I implement TypeAdapterFactory in Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307382/how-to-implement-typeadapterfactory-in-gson/22307855#22307855)

Basically, implement the `read` method in `TypeAdapter` to create the Vector class you want. If this is not enough for you to figure it out let me know and I will try to add more detail.

You can start with something like this:

```
public enum ShapeTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    INSTANCE;

    private static class ShapeTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<BackgroundShape> {
        @Override
        public final void write(JsonWriter out, BackgroundShape value) throws IOException {
            if(value == null) {
                out.nullValue();
                return;
            }

            // Your code goes here
        }

        @Override
        public final BackgroundShape read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            if(in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                in.nextNull();
                return null;
            }

            // Your code goes here      

            // Don't return null, return the new object
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if(!BackgroundShape.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        }

        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new ShapeTypeAdapter();
    }
}
```

Then register it with:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(ShapeTypeAdapterFactory.INSTANCE);
```

Also, read this Javadoc for a more complete example about how to write the code missing from this sample

- [JsonReader](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)
- [JsonWriter](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html)

Comment: Hm, the link you provided mentions creating `TypeAdapterFactory` to handle the multiple possible sub-classes of `BackgroundShape` .. Could you help there please?