# Ignore the Jackson JsonIdentityInfo during serialization

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson, gson

I'm currently using the `@JsonIdentityInfo` during deserialization and during serialization at some point in my application (During communication with certain clients) but some of my other clients simply can't use the `@JsonIdentityInfo`, is there away of ignoring it during serialization on some methods in spring?

For example:

```
[{id:5, innerobject:{id:1, name:"inner"}},
{id:6, innerobject:{id:1}}]
```

The second object with `id:6` does not have a full `innerobject`, instead it uses the `@JsonIdentityInfo` to ignore the rest (As we already have it)

**Focussing on the JacksonIdentityInfo (Server side), rather than focussing on the clientside as pointed out in the potential duplicate, which it is not. This is Jackson, not Gson.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring JSON serialization, Gson deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985242/spring-json-serialization-gson-deserialization)

Comment: But it's not a duplicate... It's a different question entirely. Granted, the examples are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way, but with bit of hackery it should be possible. The thing you can do is to create a custom sub-class of `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, override methods that look for `@JsonIdentityInfo`, and prevent them from detecting annotations.

Methods that seem to need overriding are `findObjectIdInfo()` and possibly `findObjectReferenceInfo()`. Just return `null` from both.

You can then register this introspector with `ObjectMapper`, and all reads using that mapper would work similar to removing of the annotation.
Note that you can not dynamically change introspector: it must be set/changed before usage. So if you want to enable them in some context, you need to use 2 separate mappers.

As to how to configure Spring to use this I don't know, but you may want to sub-class `ObjectMapper` (`MyNoObjectIdMapper extends ObjectMapper`) and make it configure itself on constructor.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I just went for ripping out Gson to replace it with Jackson (Which was surprisingly easy)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to StaxMan, his approach worked for me. Below is the code snippet:

- Custom JacksonAnnotationIntrospector to id creation:

---

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.ObjectIdInfo;

public class CustomJacksonAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
 
    @Override
    public ObjectIdInfo findObjectIdInfo(Annotated ann) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectIdInfo findObjectReferenceInfo(Annotated ann, ObjectIdInfo objectIdInfo) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

- To set it in mapper -

---

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
```

---