# How to replace JsonIdentityInfo's id with the full object?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonidentityinfo

My question is similar to [deserialize Jackson object in JavaScript containing JsonIdentityInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208167/deserialize-jackson-object-in-javascript-containing-jsonidentityinfo) but I'm working with Java and I'm asking about jackson specifically, not 3rd party stuff.

I'm sending JSON from the server to the client. To save space I'm using `@JsonIdentityInfo` and the client receives:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nestedObject": {
      "id": 2,
      "someInt": 2,
      "someString": "a"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nestedObject": 2
  }
]
```

But the client needs the real/full JSON representation because it's working with parsers which are not JsonIdentityInfo-aware. Does Jackson have a way to "halfway deserialize" the compact representation into the full representation?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nestedObject": {
      "id": 2,
      "someInt": 2,
      "someString": "a"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nestedObject": {
      "id": 2,
      "someInt": 2,
      "someString": "a"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Only if new functionality will be written by Sherlock. Seems like you need to use Jackson views. Check this link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279782/what-is-the-json-view-class-in-jackson-and-how-does-it-work.

Comment: @eg04lt3r i don't see how that solves anything. The link shows how to send 2 different JSON representations per demand. I want to send only one.

Comment: seems like jackson has not functionality to deserialize properly object marked as `@JsonIdentityInfo`. I think that only possible solution is to write custom deserializer. A lot of guys asked for this, but there is no solution out of the box in jackson.

Comment: Below approach helped in resolving similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76514182/11475829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more research it seems it's impossible to do at this moment, as said in the comments.